# Is it possible to set the font size of the BadgeText in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to set the font size for the `BadgeText` of the Chrome extension?

I've found only possibilities to directly set the text and the `background-color` of it. Are there maybe any methods to manipulate the `font-size` non-directly?

Comment: Not possible. All the methods are listed in the documentation.

Comment: Understand, thank you. But how to design the badge text for the best readability?

Comment: You can draw on the icon itself using Canvas API, see [google chrome extension canvas icon](//stackoverflow.com/a/29059608)